# Problem in running eclipse 3.6 on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I am trying to run eclipse 3.6 on ubuntu 10.04. I am getting these errors:

```
** (Eclipse:13709): CRITICAL **: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1' failed

** (Eclipse:16806): CRITICAL **: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1' failed

** (Eclipse:16806): CRITICAL **: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1' failed

** (Eclipse:16806): CRITICAL **: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1' failed

** (Eclipse:16806): CRITICAL **: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1' failed
```

And this causes the tool bar has big height. Is there a way to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

it's a problem related to gtk and not to eclipse or emacs.

try this (solved to me) :

Modify the entry in /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc from GtkRange::trough-under-steppers = 0 to GtkRange::trough-under-steppers = 1.

thanks to http://thehacklist.blogspot.com/2010/06/resolving-murrinestyledrawbox-assertion.html

[]s
pedro

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [bug 305843](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=305843)

It should be fixed in Eclipse Helios 3.6RC4 and more.
If you have the final Eclipse Helios 3.6 version, you may have to open a new bug report.

Comment: I am using eclipse 3.6 final, but I am still seeing the problem. And that bug is not the same bug I am talking about.

Comment: @michael: good to know, it looks like a new bug report should be created then.